# Python 2.6 Scapy rdpcap error

Tags: python, scapy

I'm new to the forum and new to Python programming in general and I have a question regarding the scapy module.

I'm trying to open a TCP dump file, and whenever I try to open the file using the command:

```
a=rdpcap("/directories/filename.pcap")
```

I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: DNS RR premature end (ofs=46, len=44)

WARNING: more DNS RR premature end (ofs=12, len=2)

WARNING: DNS incomplete jump token at (ofs=78)
```

*the ofs and len value varies of course

eventually scapy and python would just crash. Just wondering if this is a problem with the file or something wrong with my scapy.

Thanks

Comment: can you dump the pcap with tcpdump -r or read them in wireshark? If so that leads to me believe the pcap is well formed.

Comment: its a file for a school project. I got it as a .dmp file and I was able to open it with wireshark. I tried to capture a file with wireshark and open it with rdpcap and it worked fine, but the tcmp dump file still wont work.

Answer (score 1):

I know... it has been a while since this question uploaded, but I came across the same warnings in a slightly different way. I wanted to read with packets using the scrappy `sniff` function, 
Nearly every time a DNS-Response was handled I got the Warning "`WARNING: DNS RR premature end`" with the Effect that the DNS-Response was not readable when it arrived at its destination. After a while I figured out that the DNS response was split in Raw and Padding. I guess due to the decoding of the DNS-Packet with scapy it 'grew'. Therefor the attributs `ip.len` and `udp.len` are no longer correct.

In my case I was able to correct that before I sent the Response again. After that the Program worked and there were no longer warnings.  I guess due to the decoding of the DNS-Packet with scapy it 'grew'. Therefor the attributes `IP.length` and `UDP.length` are no longer correct.

In my case I was able to correct that before I sent the Response again. After that the Program worked and there were no longer warnings.

Answer (score 0):

FTR this was a bug with Scapy. It got fixed